# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap' (macOS)

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

When installing [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/#pip-install-pytorch) using `pip install torch` I get the following:

```
from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'
```

I'm on macOS 10.14.4, Python 3.8.

I read through the [thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859803/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tools-nnwrap) but it didn't help.

---

**UPDATE 13/11/19**

The accepted answer works.

As a side note, I finally setup my local environment using [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/), despite the meaty installation creating an enviroment has been easy:

```sh
#create the env
conda create -n mytensorflowenv python=3.7

#activate it
conda activate mytensorflowenv
```

then run the [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/#python) installation for Conda:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
```

All smooth now.

Comment: `pip3 install torch torchvision`

Comment: @Craicerjack outputs the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as per https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/29090

Python 3.8 binaries are not yet available.

You'll need to downgrade your python version to 3.7