# how to install torch package through terminal or through pycharm

Tags: python, torch

Iam trying to install torch package through command prompt but I keep getting this error

```
R: Command errored out with exit status 1:                                                                           command: 'C:\Users\kaisios\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\kaisios\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qoiahbzi\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\kaisios\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qoiahbzi\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\kaisios\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-9mgn8ll8' --python-tag cp37
       cwd: C:\Users\kaisios\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qoiahbzi\torch\
  Complete output (30 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_deps
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\kaisios\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qoiahbzi\torch\setup.py", line 265, in <module>
      description="Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration",
    File "C:\Users\kaisios\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\Users\kaisios\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\kaisios\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\kaisios\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\kaisios\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 192, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Users\kaisios\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\kaisios\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\kaisios\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)                                                                                            File "C:\Users\kaisios\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command                                          self.distribution.run_command(command)                                                                                File "C:\Users\kaisios\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\kaisios\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qoiahbzi\torch\setup.py", line 51, in run
      from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'                                                                     ----------------------------------------                                                                                ERROR: Failed building wheel for torch
  Running setup.py clean for torch                                                                                        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:                                                                           command: 'C:\Users\kaisios\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\kaisios\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qoiahbzi\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\kaisios\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qoiahbzi\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
       cwd: C:\Users\kaisios\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qoiahbzi\torch
  Complete output (2 lines):
  running clean
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.gitignore'                                                                ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for torch
Failed to build torch
Installing collected packages: torch, torchvision
  Running setup.py install for torch ... error                                                                              ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:                                                                           command: 'C:\Users\kaisios\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\kaisios\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qoiahbzi\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\kaisios\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qoiahbzi\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\kaisios\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-di7tzuhu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
         cwd: C:\Users\kaisios\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qoiahbzi\torch\                                               Complete output (23 lines):                                                                                             running install                                                                                                         running build_deps                                                                                                      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\kaisios\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qoiahbzi\torch\setup.py", line 265, in <module>
        description="Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration",
      File "C:\Users\kaisios\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 145, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Users\kaisios\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\kaisios\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\kaisios\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\kaisios\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qoiahbzi\torch\setup.py", line 99, in run
        self.run_command('build_deps')
      File "C:\Users\kaisios\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\kaisios\Anaconda3\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\kaisios\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qoiahbzi\torch\setup.py", line 51, in run
        from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'                                                                     ----------------------------------------                                                                            ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\kaisios\Anaconda3\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\kaisios\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qoiahbzi\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\kaisios\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qoiahbzi\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\kaisios\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-di7tzuhu\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

please help to solve the problem

Comment: It would be easier if you formatted the output some.
I'd say this is a duplicate of <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859803/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tools-nnwrap>

Comment: what command did you use?

Comment: I am using pycharm and I tried to install through pip and conda and it has been installed but still pycharm could't see it