# could not install pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, pip

```
C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37>python -m pip install torch
Collecting torch
  Downloading torch-0.1.2.post2.tar.gz (128 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 128 kB 218 kB/s
Collecting pyyaml
  Downloading PyYAML-5.3.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (216 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 216 kB 595 kB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: torch

  Building wheel for torch (setup.py) ... error

  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

   command: 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1cm70dkz\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1cm70dkz\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-hdou79z2'
       cwd: C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1cm70dkz\torch\
  Complete output (30 lines):

  running bdist_wheel

  running build

  running build_deps

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1cm70dkz\torch\setup.py", line 265, in <module>
      description="Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration",

    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)

    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()

    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)

    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()

    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 290, in run
      self.run_command('build')

    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)

    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()

    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)

    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)

    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()

    File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1cm70dkz\torch\setup.py", line 51, in run
      from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'

  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for torch
  Running setup.py clean for torch
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1cm70dkz\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1cm70dkz\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
       cwd: C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1cm70dkz\torch
  Complete output (2 lines):
  running clean
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.gitignore'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for torch
Failed to build torch
Installing collected packages: pyyaml, torch
    Running setup.py install for torch ... error

    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

     command: 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1cm70dkz\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1cm70dkz\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-lrcjmcqq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Include\torch'
         cwd: C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1cm70dkz\torch\
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running install
    running build_deps
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1cm70dkz\torch\setup.py", line 265, in <module>
        description="Tensors and Dynamic neural networks in Python with strong GPU acceleration",
      File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()

      File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)

      File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()

      File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1cm70dkz\torch\setup.py", line 99, in run
        self.run_command('build_deps')

      File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)

      File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()

      File "C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-1cm70dkz\torch\setup.py", line 51, in run
        from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1cm70dkz\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Dell\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-1cm70dkz\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-lrcjmcqq\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Include\torch' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859803/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tools-nnwrap)

Comment: You can see from the log: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'`