# Pip doesn't work, says it cannot build wheels

Tags: python, windows, pip

*I've looked online for a solution but haven't found one.*

I have a new computer which is the first desktop I own and I need to install python and pip and all these things for a high school project, but when installing PyTorch and other packages I need I am met with this error:

```
C:\Users\Owlsoul>pip3 install torch
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting torch
  Using cached torch-0.1.2.post2.tar.gz (128 kB)
Collecting pyyaml
  Using cached PyYAML-5.3.1.tar.gz (269 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: torch, pyyaml
  Building wheel for torch (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\program files\inkscape\bin\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Owlsoul\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hw6a8m3j\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Owlsoul\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hw6a8m3j\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-kmaghkld'
       cwd: C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hw6a8m3j\torch\
  Complete output (30 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_deps
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hw6a8m3j\torch\setup.py", line 225, in <module>
      setup(name="torch", version="0.1.2.post2",
    File "C:\Users\Owlsoul\.local\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Owlsoul\.local\lib\python3.8\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 290, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hw6a8m3j\torch\setup.py", line 51, in run
      from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for torch
  Running setup.py clean for torch
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\program files\inkscape\bin\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Owlsoul\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hw6a8m3j\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Owlsoul\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hw6a8m3j\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
       cwd: C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hw6a8m3j\torch
  Complete output (2 lines):
  running clean
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.gitignore'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for torch
  Building wheel for pyyaml (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\program files\inkscape\bin\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Owlsoul\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hw6a8m3j\\pyyaml\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Owlsoul\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hw6a8m3j\\pyyaml\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-nztx1z7u'
       cwd: C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hw6a8m3j\pyyaml\
  Complete output (59 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.mingw-3.8
  creating build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
  copying lib3\yaml\composer.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
  copying lib3\yaml\constructor.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
  copying lib3\yaml\cyaml.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
  copying lib3\yaml\dumper.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
  copying lib3\yaml\emitter.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
  copying lib3\yaml\error.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
  copying lib3\yaml\events.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
  copying lib3\yaml\loader.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
  copying lib3\yaml\nodes.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
  copying lib3\yaml\parser.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
  copying lib3\yaml\reader.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
  copying lib3\yaml\representer.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
  copying lib3\yaml\resolver.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
  copying lib3\yaml\scanner.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
  copying lib3\yaml\serializer.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
  copying lib3\yaml\tokens.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
  copying lib3\yaml\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
  running build_ext
  'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hw6a8m3j\pyyaml\setup.py", line 291, in <module>
      setup(
    File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Owlsoul\.local\lib\python3.8\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 290, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hw6a8m3j\pyyaml\setup.py", line 185, in run
      _build_ext.run(self)
    File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 307, in run
      self.compiler = new_compiler(compiler=self.compiler,
    File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1034, in new_compiler
      return klass(None, dry_run, force)
    File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 310, in __init__
      CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose, dry_run, force)
    File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 127, in __init__
      if self.ld_version >= "2.10.90":
  TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyyaml
  Running setup.py clean for pyyaml
Failed to build torch pyyaml
Installing collected packages: pyyaml, torch
    Running setup.py install for pyyaml ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files\inkscape\bin\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Owlsoul\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hw6a8m3j\\pyyaml\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Owlsoul\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hw6a8m3j\\pyyaml\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-v7hld7x2\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Owlsoul\.local\include\python3.8\pyyaml'
         cwd: C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hw6a8m3j\pyyaml\
    Complete output (61 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.mingw-3.8
    creating build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
    copying lib3\yaml\composer.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
    copying lib3\yaml\constructor.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
    copying lib3\yaml\cyaml.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
    copying lib3\yaml\dumper.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
    copying lib3\yaml\emitter.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
    copying lib3\yaml\error.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
    copying lib3\yaml\events.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
    copying lib3\yaml\loader.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
    copying lib3\yaml\nodes.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
    copying lib3\yaml\parser.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
    copying lib3\yaml\reader.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
    copying lib3\yaml\representer.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
    copying lib3\yaml\resolver.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
    copying lib3\yaml\scanner.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
    copying lib3\yaml\serializer.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
    copying lib3\yaml\tokens.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
    copying lib3\yaml\__init__.py -> build\lib.mingw-3.8\yaml
    running build_ext
    'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    operable program or batch file.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hw6a8m3j\pyyaml\setup.py", line 291, in <module>
        setup(
      File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Owlsoul\.local\lib\python3.8\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\command\install.py", line 546, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hw6a8m3j\pyyaml\setup.py", line 185, in run
        _build_ext.run(self)
      File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 307, in run
        self.compiler = new_compiler(compiler=self.compiler,
      File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1034, in new_compiler
        return klass(None, dry_run, force)
      File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 310, in __init__
        CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose, dry_run, force)
      File "C:\program files\inkscape\lib\python3.8\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 127, in __init__
        if self.ld_version >= "2.10.90":
    TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'str'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files\inkscape\bin\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Owlsoul\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hw6a8m3j\\pyyaml\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Owlsoul\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hw6a8m3j\\pyyaml\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-v7hld7x2\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Owlsoul\.local\include\python3.8\pyyaml' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

After following your advice, a new error has popped up:

```
C:\Users\Owlsoul>pip install torch
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting torch
  Using cached torch-0.1.2.post2.tar.gz (128 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyyaml in c:\users\owlsoul\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from torch) (5.3.1)
Building wheels for collected packages: torch
  Building wheel for torch (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Owlsoul\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jio16_76\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Owlsoul\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jio16_76\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-iuye_5re'
       cwd: C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jio16_76\torch\
  Complete output (30 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_deps
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jio16_76\torch\setup.py", line 225, in <module>
      setup(name="torch", version="0.1.2.post2",
    File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 290, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jio16_76\torch\setup.py", line 51, in run
      from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for torch
  Running setup.py clean for torch
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Owlsoul\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jio16_76\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Owlsoul\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jio16_76\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' clean --all
       cwd: C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jio16_76\torch
  Complete output (2 lines):
  running clean
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.gitignore'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for torch
Failed to build torch
Installing collected packages: torch
    Running setup.py install for torch ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Owlsoul\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jio16_76\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Owlsoul\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jio16_76\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-z9idl5pc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Include\torch'
         cwd: C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jio16_76\torch\
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running install
    running build_deps
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jio16_76\torch\setup.py", line 225, in <module>
        setup(name="torch", version="0.1.2.post2",
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jio16_76\torch\setup.py", line 99, in run
        self.run_command('build_deps')
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jio16_76\torch\setup.py", line 51, in run
        from tools.nnwrap import generate_wrappers as generate_nn_wrappers
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files (x86)\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Owlsoul\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jio16_76\\torch\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Owlsoul\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-jio16_76\\torch\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-z9idl5pc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --user --prefix= --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Owlsoul\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\Include\torch' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: There must be more error lines. post full stacktrace.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that in a moment

Comment: Are you using python x32 or x64?

Comment: I have x64 installed

Comment: And your system is x64 as well?

Comment: I think so, how can i check?

Comment: ok yeah it is, i checked in system information

Comment: You new error is addressed by [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859803/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tools-nnwrap) (remember that updating your situation also generally requires doing a search for new error messages =)

Answer (score 0):

Note that your error is caused by `c:\program files\inkscape\bin\python.exe`, which is *almost certainly* entirely the wrong python executable, because that's not where python installs itself.

Uninstall whatever you installed, then grab the latest installer from https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/, run that (with admin rights, because *hopefully* you remembered to make sure your own account is set to a normal account type and NOT an admin account, for obvious security reasons), then when that's finished installing, make sure to update your PATH:

- run "advanced system settings"
- click the "environment variables" button
- double click the `PATH` entry in "system variables" section
- verify that both `C:\Program Files\Python38\` and `C:\Program Files\Python38\Scripts\` are in there. If not, add them. (or whatever the location is you custom-installed them to of course).
- possibly necessary: also check to see if there is an Inkscape entry in your Path. If there is, use the "move up"/"move down" buttons to make sure that the Python entries are listed *above* the Inkscape entry.

Then you can start cmd/powershell/etc with admin rights (if you already had one open, close it and start a new one for the updated PATH to be in effect) and just use `pip` (not `pip3`) to install packages globally.

That said, for projects you almost always want to use python's "virtualenv" concept, explained over on https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html, which lets you install dependencies locally, which means that if one project requires, say, Django 2.10 and another requires Djangoo 3.0, each of them installs in their own virtual environment, instead of causing a global dependency conflict.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot I am currently installing again python and have changed the path so I think it should work

Comment: Also make sure that your Python locations are _above_ the `c:\program files\inkscape\bin` entry in your PATH. The PATH list is checked in order, so if your Python entries are last, Windows will still find Inkscape's version of Python first and try to run that instead of the proper version.

Comment: i uninstalled inkscape completely as i won't use it much

Comment: Unless you say what the error is, that's not information I can do with. If you update your post with the new error, I (and others) can address it.

Comment: I am editing the original message to include the new error. *I don't know if it translates well to my writing but I really appreciate the help*

Comment: Also remember that if you get a new error, you are entirely able to search for that neew error: it looks like you're now hitting a normal problem instead of a pip related one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859803/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tools-nnwrap

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I ended up using anaconda and it worked. Thanks a lot, but setting these things up drives me nuts and I may not have the skill to understand a lot of the instructions...