# Can't install PyTorch

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

Encountered the next problem while trying to install pytorch
I've got 64-bit version of python, pip and setuptools were updated

[Beginning of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhBh6.png)

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzwbd.png)

Comment: potentially related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859803/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tools-nnwrap

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!
This helped: `pip install torch==1.6.0+cpu torchvision==0.7.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`