# PyTorch import broken, unable to pip install

Tags: python, pytorch, archlinux

So all of a sudden my code broke. Error: Unable to import torch, `No module named torch`. So I attempt to install torch; error, `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tools.nnwrap'`. I delete my venv and re-create it, same thing. I try it outside the venv, same issue. I look up the issue, apparently I should go [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/). I do, try several of the install commands, with cuda, without, all broken. What do I do? Am on Arch Linux if that's relevant, maybe I broke something.

Comment: If you ran a ```pacman -Syu``` yesterday, it's possible it has to do with the new python release. Does a ```python3 -m venv --upgrade .``` help?

Comment: I did run an update recently, but updating the venv doesn't help :(

Comment: If you're still stuck, please send your exact requirements for your venv, and I can try replicating it. I'm on the same OS

Comment: It's just Python 3.9. I've tried this in the venv and outside it. Nothing seems to work. All other packages seem to work. If I try to use one of the more specific commands I get something like ```ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.7.0+cpu (from versions: 0.1.2, 0.1.2.post1, 0.1.2.post2)```

Comment: Any chance you could send me your ```requirements.txt``` so I can see if I can make it work?

Comment: Nevermind, I can confirm I'm getting the same error if I try to install ```torch==1.7.0+cpu```. I'll look into it when I have the time

Comment: Thank you, but as it turns out PyTorch just doesn't work with Python 3.9 :(. I've downgraded and managed it to work now.

Comment: I'm the one whose answer you accepted, so believe me, I know it doesn't :P

Comment: Ah right, my mistake :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/47116

It's a recent issue with Python 3.9, as expected: it's sadly not compatible with PyTorch as of right now (04/12/2020), and the error message isn't explicit about it. The issue is currently still open and pending, and all you can do is revert to 3.8 for the time being.

Comment: Damn, well ok, I guess I now just have to figure out how to downgrade my python

Answer (score 0):

If you use pip, take a pip installation link from [here](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) and replace `pip`with `pip3`.
This resolved my problem with `No module named 'tools.nnwrap'` a few days ago.

Tested on Python 3.8.6, Windows 10

**Example**

Use `pip3 install torch==1.7.0+cpu torchvision==0.8.1+cpu torchaudio===0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

instead of `pip install torch==1.7.0+cpu torchvision==0.8.1+cpu torchaudio===0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html`

**Edit**

[Stack post on the same topic that could help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56859803/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-tools-nnwrap)

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that post, and no, it doesn't seem to help :(